# Focus on input inside ngFor

Tags: angular, focus

When user clicks on button, `addElement` method will push object to array of `elements` and new input field will be created. Is it possible to focus on the newly created element? Inputs don't have distinctive IDs.

Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let foo of elements">
  <input class="input" value="{{ foo.value }}" />
</div>
<button (click)="addElement()"></button>
```

Method:

```js
public addElement() {
  this.elements.push({ value: 'new' });
}
```

I'm using Angular 9 in this application.

Comment: I think there is noway around setting IDs of the input and then calling focus() on them. The autofocus attribute cannot be used since it needs the page to reload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to query all inputs via `ViewChildren` decorator, then every time `addElement` called the `ngAfterViewChecked` will be called too. So you may use this hook to focus the last already created input.

```html
<div *ngFor="let foo of elements">
  <input 
    #input 
    class="input" 
    [value]="foo.value"
  />
</div>
<button (click)="addElement()"></button>
```

```js
@ViewChildren('input') inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

addElement() {
  this.elements.push({ value: 'new' });
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.inputs.last.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Otherwise you can do check by yourself and don't rely on lifecycle hook because this logic in `ngAfterViewChecked` may affect smth in your app:

```js
@ViewChildren('input') inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

addElement() {
  this.elements.push({ value: 'new' });
  /* run change detection manually to create input element and have access to the last input */
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.inputs.last.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

---

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence

Answer (score 3):

Angular Elements inside ngFor can be accessed using `ViewChildren`.

You can update your `addElement` function in the following way to achieve the results.

```
@ViewChildren("row") rows;
public addElement() {
    this.elements.push({ value: "new" });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.rows.last.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
```

And update your ngFor Template as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of elements">
  <input #row class="input" value="{{ foo.value }}" />
</div>
```

Here is the example stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtkvaz

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this goal by tracking any change in child components of your div. Each time `div` is created or refreshed, set focus on last `input` child.

To do that, you need :

- one directive to add some behavior logic to `div` container
- one directive to identity each `input` tag

In this way, your template could be :

```
<div track-focus *ngFor="let foo of elements">
  <input auto-focus ... />
</div>
<button (click)="addElement()">Add</button>
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[auto-focus]',
})
export class InputAutoFocusDirective {}
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[track-focus]',
})
export class TrackFocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(InputAutofocusDirective, {
    read: ElementRef,
  })
  children: QueryList<InputAutoFocusDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const input = (this.children.last as ElementRef)
      .nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    if (input) {
      input.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Here, you have a reusable solution.